# Reference/set nested XML object property using path in a string - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is not for web development. I am using ES3.

How do I get the information from the xml element `proof` using javascript in this scenario?
My way of looking for the `proof` element with `xml[xmlVariable]` doesn't work - it returns nothing. But when you enter `xml.ait.pages.proof` in the console (while the program is held by breakpoint at the `return` expression) it returns the `"desired info"` from the `proof` element correctly.

I've read up on dot/bracket notation thinking that would be the solution but nope.

What's the correct syntax here?

```xml
<root>
  <ait>
    <pages>
      <proof>desired info</proof>
    </pages>
  </ait>
</root>
```

```
var xmlFile = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\info.xml"
var xmlElementPath = "ait.pages.proof"
var info = readXMLVar(xmlElementPath, xmlFile)

function readXMLVar(xmlVariable, xmlFilePath) {
  var file = new File(xmlFilePath)
  file.open("r")
  var content = file.read()
  file.close()
  var xml = new XML(content)
  return xml[xmlVariable]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applied fixes to JAAulde's answer and some slight modifications to fit into my function. Here is my code to get ***and*** set XML variables.

`!(Object.prototype.toString.call(path) === '[object Array]')` is used in place of `!Array.isArray(path)` because I'm forced to use ES3.

```
function readXMLFile(xmlFilePath) {
  var file = new File(xmlFilePath)
  file.open("r")
  var content = file.read()
  file.close()
  return [file, new XML(content)]
}

function getXMLVar(xmlFilePath, nodePath, separator) {
  var xml = readXMLFile(xmlFilePath)[1]
  
  // navigate xml to return target node info
  var getNodeFromPath = function(data, path, separator) {
    var node_name,
    node,
    ret
    
    if(!(Object.prototype.toString.call(path) === '[object Array]')) {
      path = path.split(separator || '.')
    }
    node_name = path.shift()
    node = data[node_name]
    
    if(node === undefined) {
      ret = null
    } else {
      if(path.length) {
        ret = getNodeFromPath(node, path, separator)
      } else {
        ret = node
      }
    }
    return ret
  }
  
  return getNodeFromPath(xml, nodePath, separator)
}

function setXMLVar(xmlFilePath, nodePath, separator, value) {
  var read = readXMLFile(xmlFilePath)
  var file = read[0]
  var xml = read[1]

  setNodeFromPath = function(data, path, separator, value) {
    var node_name,
    node
    
    if(!(Object.prototype.toString.call(path) === '[object Array]')) {
      path = path.split(separator || '.')
    }
    node_name = path.shift()
    node = data[node_name]
    
    if(path.length > 1) {
      setNodeFromPath(node, path, separator, value)
    } else {
      node[path[0]] = value
    }
  }
  
  setNodeFromPath(xml, nodePath, separator, value)
  
  file.open("w")
  file.write(xml)
  file.close()
}
```

Comment: I'm glad this works. I would caution you, though, against writing such highly coupled code. The read of the XML file should be wholly separate from the code that can "walk" a path, which should be separate from your implementation code.

Comment: Also, the issue is that I also made a setter function version of the recursive code which gets the info from a node. They're slightly different enough to be different functions code blocks entirely. I don't know if there's a good way to make a single function that does both getting and setting concisely.

Answer (score 0):

For XML I would probably query using XPath. The code you're using, however, seems to create an object structure from the parsed XML, and you then want to ask for a part of that structure using a path to it, as it were.

You can use square bracket notation as you tried, but you have to do it one property/node-level at a time. JS doesn't parse the dot separated path you provided to walk into the nested structure.

As such, you need something that can break apart the path you want, and recursively walk down the structure node by node.

Here is a basic function that can walk an object structure:

```
var getNodeFromPath = function (data, path, separator) {
    var node_name,
        node,
        ret;

    if (!Array.isArray(path)) {
        path = path.split(separator || '.');
    }

    node_name = path.shift();

    node = data[node_name];

    if (node === undefined) {
        ret = null;
    } else {
        if (path.length) {
            ret = getNodeFromPath(node, path);
        } else {
            ret = node;
        }
    }

    return ret;
};
```

You could call it like so:

```
var proof_element = getNodeFromPath(yourParsedXmlData, 'ait.pages.proof');
```

Note that the function I gave you has minimal control in it. You'll probably want to add some checking to make it more resistant to arbitrary input data/path problems.

Comment: It seems to be working perfectly. Thanks so much! I had to change a few things since: I'm using ES3, I think you accidentally made an error or two, and also to get it working in my function. See my post below.

Comment: I'm not sure what errors you think I made, but it is true that the code I wrote isn't workable in ES3. That said, without being _overly specific_ to your _exact use case_, this did answer your _actual_ question of how to access a nested property with a path denoted in a string.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Thanks! You put `walkNodePath` inside the anonymous function which had a different name. So it was telling me `walkNodePath` didn't exist, therefore breaking the recursion. Also not the same number of args. And I only changed the isArray line to make it ES3 compatible.

Comment: Ooohhh, I’m sorry. I had change the name of the function and missed that reference :/